# Finding words with one vowel group

Tags: awk, grep, string

I am trying to use a command to find all words in a list of words with one group vowels. Like four, for and far, but also words like ore and or.

What I got so far:

```
grep -i ^[qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm]*[aeodsui]+[qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm]$
```

But this also gives words like vowel.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "vowel group"? Can you please include a list of input words and which words you expect your `grep` to select?

Comment: Don't know why you wrote it as keyboard layout but if you had sorted, it would make a lot more sense as `^[a-cf-hj-np-rtv-z][adeiosu][[a-cf-hj-np-rtv-z]`

Answer (score 0):

What you have is very close, simply replace `grep -i` with `egrep`, i.e.

```
egrep ^[qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm]*[aeodsui]+[qwrtypsdfghjklzxcvbnm]$ [filename]
```

should do the trick.

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated, you should use `grep -E`